# How can I remove some code in markdown HTML?

Tags: markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I want to hide the red circle part. How can I do?

[image]

Comment: Please include some code in you question. Do not use external images for that.

Answer (score 2):

Set your code chunk with message=FALSE:

````
```{r, message=FALSE}
library(ROCR)
```
````

You can find all sorts of options to manipulate code chunks inside of rmarkdown [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/).

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, use this as the **first** in your Rmd file,

````
```{r nomessages, echo = FALSE}
# set some default options for chunks
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  warning = FALSE,   # avoid warnings and messages in the output
  message = FALSE)
```
````